# re.sub for a csv file

Tags: python, regex

I am receiving a error on this code. It is "TypeError: expected string or buffer". I looked around, and found out that the error is because I am passing re.sub a list, and it does not take lists. However, I wasn't able to figure out how to change my line from the csv file into something that it would read.

I am trying to change all the periods in a csv file into commas. Here is my code:

```
import csv  
import re  

in_file = open("/test.csv", "rb")  
reader = csv.reader(in_file)  
out_file = open("/out.csv", "wb")  
writer = csv.writer(out_file)  

for row in reader:   
    newrow = re.sub(r"(\.)+", ",", row)  
    writer.writerow(newrow)

in_file.close()  
out_file.close()
```

I'm sorry if this has already been answered somewhere. There was certainly a lot of answers regarding this error, but I couldn't make any of them work with my csv file. Also, as a side note, this was originally an .xslb excel file that I converted into csv in order to be able to work with it. Was that necessary?

Comment: `row` is a list of items not a string  https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use list comprehension to apply your substitution to each item in `row`

```
for row in reader:   
    newrow = [re.sub(r"(\.)+", ",", item) for item in row]
    writer.writerow(newrow)
```

Comment: That worked exactly how I wanted it to, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

`for row in reader` does not return single element to parse it rather it returns list of of elements in that `row` so you have to unpack that list and parse each item individually, just like @Trii shew you:

```
[re.sub(r'(\.)+','.',s) for s in row]
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, we are using `glob` to access all the `csv` files in the directory.
The code below overwrites the source `csv` file, so there is no need to create an output file.

NOTE:

If you want to get a second file with the parameters provided with `re.sub`, replace `write = open(i, 'w')` for `write = open('secondFile.csv', 'w')`

```
import re
import glob

for i in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    read = open(i, 'r')
    reader = read.read()
    csvRe = re.sub(re.sub(r"(\.)+", ",", str(reader))
    write = open(i, 'w')
    write.write(csvRe)
    read.close()
    write.close()
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.